# How can I properly bind a React component class's event handlers when converting from createClass to the class keyword?

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, this, property-initializer

I'm in the midst of preparing our React components for an upgrade to React 16 with the crux of that process being an update of components that use with `React.createClass` to use the `class` keyword instead.

I'm running into trouble when it comes to event handlers that invoke class methods as I keep seeing the `Can only update a mounted or mounting component` error.

A trivial example...

Original component using `React.createClass`:

```
const Foo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { bar: false };
  },

  onClick() {
    this.setState({ bar: !this.state.bar });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.bar ? 'YAY' : 'BOO'}</p>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>CLICK IT</button>
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

That works as expected. So does this if I'm willing to ignore that a new function object will be created with each call to `render`:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { bar: false };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.bar ? 'YAY' : 'BOO'}</p>
        <button onClick={() => { this.setState({ bar: !this.state.bar }); }}>CLICK IT</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However, I can't get the "bind in the constructor" approach to work:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { bar: false };

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick() {
    this.setState({ bar: !this.state.bar });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.bar ? 'YAY' : 'BOO'}</p>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>CLICK IT</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Nor can I get the property initializer syntax approach to work:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { bar: false };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ bar: !this.state.bar });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.bar ? 'YAY' : 'BOO'}</p>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>CLICK IT</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In both of those cases, whenever I click the button the aforementioned error message shows up in the browser console.

I'm hoping someone has encountered this problem themselves already and has advice on how to deal with it. I imagine that it's just something trivial that I'm completely overlooking. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `onClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({bar: !prevState.bar }));
  }`

Comment: That's a separate issue; either binding method works properly.

Comment: For class properties to work, you need to transform them. They are not included in a Babel preset right now because they are still a proposal. You need to enable [stage-2](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/).

Comment: The `Can only update a mounted or mounting component` error means that `setState` is being called on the component instance correctly but that the instance has either not been mounted or is already unmounted. Are you running the exact code you are posting here?

Comment: @RossAllen I have `stage-2` enabled.

Comment: @RossAllen I understand the general gist of the error having seen it in other scenarios. I'm just stuck on why it's showing up in this particular scenario and only with certain component design approaches. My "real" code is obviously much more complex than this example, but this example is a dummy component I did use in order to verify that it wasn't just the one particular component.

Comment: @AndrewLi "Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Foo component." There's also a stack trace with file names and line numbers but I'm not sure that would be helpful. LOL

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri That didn't work, either.

Comment: I put together a quick barebones `create-react-app` app and saw everything working fine in there so this is just an issue with our specific app. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at React Documentation: They have the same example.  BTW your bind example works for me: post your error message.

```
 class Toggle extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }

   handleClick() {
     this.setState(prevState => ({
       isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
     }));
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
         </button>
      );
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Toggle />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: The error message is pretty standard: "Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Foo component."

Comment: I tested in a barebones `create-react-app` app and verified that it's working there so it's just an issue with how the app is set up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pshh, do it the easy way and use [react-autobind](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autobind). Binds all component functions to `this` for you automatically in the constructor.

Super simple and easy to use:

```
import autoBind from 'react-autobind';

constructor() {
  super();
  autoBind(this);
}
```

Comment: That sounds like cheating! ;)

In all seriousness, I don't think that would work. There's a problem in the app that I'm trying to pinpoint. The syntax is correct since I can get the class to work in a barebones `create-react-app` app so there's something else going on that's screwing up how React components are binding.

Answer (score 0):

Was having this exact problem after porting some code from an electron app to the web.

`"transform-es2015-classes"` is what you need!

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes`

More info @ the [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-classes/)